# Having in QueryOver

Tags: c#, nhibernate, orm, queryover

we are struggling with the following problem.. ORM solution of our choice is NHibernate and we want to write queries using QueryOver style.. Right now there is a new puzzle to solve, we want to make a query like:

```
select sp.Id, SUM(p.PriceAmount), SUM(i.BruttoAmount)  from SellerProfile sp
left join SellerProfile_Invoice spi on spi.SellerProfile = sp.Id
left join Invoice i on spi.Invoice = i.Id
left join SellerProfile_Payment spp on spp.SellerProfile = sp.Id
left join Payment p on spp.Payment = p.Id
where i.PaymentDate < '2011-07-12'
group by sp.Id
having SUM(ISNULL(p.PriceAmount,0)) - SUM(ISNULL(i.BruttoAmount,0)) < 0
```

So we've wrote code like this:

```
Invoice invoice = null;
Payment payment = null;
SellerProfile seller = null;

var sellerIds = Session.QueryOver<SellerProfile>(() => seller)
                .Left.JoinQueryOver(() => seller.Payments, () => payment)
                .Left.JoinQueryOver(() => seller.Invoices, () => invoice)
                .Where(() => invoice.PaymentDate < DateTime.Now - timeSpan)
                .Select(Projections.Group(() => seller.Id))
                .Where(Restrictions.Lt(new ArithmeticOperatorProjection("-", NHibernateUtil.Decimal, Projections.Sum(() => payment.Price.Amount), Projections.Sum(() => invoice.Brutto.Amount)), 0)).List<int>();
```

Generated SQL looks like this:

```
SELECT this_.Id as y0_ 
FROM SellerProfile this_ inner join ResourceOwner this_1_ on this_.Id=this_1_.Id 
inner join Resource this_2_ on this_.Id=this_2_.Id
left outer join SellerProfile_Payment payments4_ on this_.Id=payments4_.SellerProfile
left outer join Payment payment2_ on payments4_.Payment=payment2_.Id
left outer join SellerProfile_Invoice invoices6_ on this_.Id=invoices6_.SellerProfile
left outer join Invoice invoice1_ on invoices6_.Invoice=invoice1_.Id
WHERE invoice1_.PaymentDate < @p0
and (sum(payment2_.PriceAmount) - sum(invoice1_.BruttoAmount)) < @p1
GROUP BY this_.Id
```

But it's throwing an exception, because it puts `and` clause to first `where` instead of `having` in the last line and our SQL does not work...

Any help? Thanks...

Comment: Which database and what is the query generated?

Comment: Database is SQL Server... Look to my post, I've added the generated SQL...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK the QueryOver, LINQ, and Criteria API does not support HAVING clause logic (NH 3.1)

You can use HQL though.

[HQL Examples](http://knol.google.com/k/nhibernate-chapter-12-hql-the-hibernate-query-language)